# Styling issue text-center not working in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

If I simply add **text-center** inside ion-col element then it's not working. But if I add it with class attribute like **class="ion-text-center"** then it's working.I'm using ionic 5.0.0 version.

Here is the code not working for me

```
 <ion-grid>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col text-center>
    <h3>text-center</h3>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac vehicula lorem.
    <div class="ion-text-center">
    </div>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

hers is the code with class attribute, it's working

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <h3>text-center</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac vehicula lorem.
        <div class="ion-text-center">
        </div>
      </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no issue. Properties like `text-center` are [deprecated](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/issues/996) since ionic 4, and you are supposed to use `class='ion-text-center'` etc. for the same.

The browser console would've shown you the deprecation-warning on `ionic serve`.

Comment: hmm got it. Thanks for the reply